# I was trying to insert values into a table by joining 3 tables, however i am getting "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" error''

Tags: sql, oracle, join, insert

```
insert into  emp_track values (emp_id,place)  
    select e.EMPLOYEE_ID, l.STATE_PROVINCE ||'  '|| l.city as address 
    from employees e ,locations l,departments d 
    where l.location_id=d.location_id  and d.department_id=e.department_id;
```

The select statement is giving output

```
EMPLOYEE_ID ADDRESS
100         Washington Seattle
103         Texas Southlake
120         California South San Francisco
```

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT . .  INTO`  will not have `values` with `SELECT` statement, so remove it :

```
insert into emp_track (emp_id,place)
   select e.EMPLOYEE_ID, l.STATE_PROVINCE ||' '|| l.city as address 
   from employees e inner join 
        departments d 
        on d.department_id = e.department_id inner join
        location l
        on l.location_id = d.location_id;
```

Note : I have used explicit join syntax instead of comma.

Comment: @EricBrandt. . . Thank you.